# How do I get the scrollToFix plugin limit to stop at my website's footer?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, offset

I am using the [scrollToFix](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) script on my website to fix the ads as the user scrolls down the page as well as release when the user reaches the footer (so that the ads do not overlap the footer). My code below, however, causes the ads to stop scrolling between a third and half way down the page, rather than at the footer. Setting it to scroll to the outerHeight of the container minus the height of the footer leaves it stopping at that spot as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.right').scrollToFixed({
          marginTop: $('.float').outerHeight() + 8, 
          limit: $('footer').offset().top 
     });
});
```

Are there any ideas on how to get it to stop more accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because your site changes height after the document is ready, due to fonts & images etc. Try binding the event to the window `load` event.

```
$(function() {
    $('window').on('load', function() {
        $('.right').scrollToFixed({
            marginTop: $('.float').outerHeight() + 8, 
            limit: $('footer').offset().top 
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ah, you found the problem! i had to tinker with the code a bit but i think i got it, thanks so much for the pointer on waiting until page load! :D

`$(window).load(function () {
$('.right').scrollToFixed({
marginTop: $('.float').outerHeight() + 8,
limit: $('footer').offset().top - $('.right').outerHeight() - 24
});
});`

Comment: Yeah it depends on what jQuery version you're using; `.on()` is relatively new. I don't like the `.load()` function, because it does 2 completely things depending on the parameters you pass it, which is very inconsistent. [Load data from server](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and [load javascript event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). You could also use `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.right-sidebar').scrollToFixed({
     marginTop: 0,
     limit: $('.right-sidebar-parent').outerHeight() - 180 } );
    });
```

This worked for me for limiting the height dynamically.