# How to stop scrolling of inner div when end of outer div is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I have a inner **div(cube)** on my side bar **div(right)**. The **div(cube)** scrolls and have 3 divs in it. I want it to stop scrolling when the sidebar **div(right)** end is reached. But instead of stopping it crosses sidebar end.

Scroll function code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.cube').scrollToFixed({
                limit: $('end-sticky').offset().top - $('.cube').outerHeight(true),
                zIndex: 999,
                fixed: function() {  },
            });
```

html code

```
<div class="right"> //main div (sidebar)
        <div class="cube" style="margin:0;"> //scrolling div

</div>

<div>
```

css code:

```
#container .right{float:right;padding:0;width:350px;height:100%;}

#container .right .cube{margin: 0 10px 10px;}
```

Comment: @Mouser edited question to include css

Comment: Does `limit: $('end-sticky').offset().top - $('.cube').outerHeight(true)` result in a number or NaN?

Comment: @Mouser couldn't get you. I tried creating an empty **div(giving it class end)** after **div(cube)** and changed **end-sticky** in the code to **.end** but it stops scrolling of cube.

Comment: **end-sticky** seems like a bad selector. Is it a classname? If so, make sure you add the period before the classname in the selector.

Comment: @Ringo end-sticky was originally written in the code when I used it.

Comment: If you want to fix this problem, you need to post more html. At least post the html that has either a classname of "end-sticky" or a component called < end-sticky>

Comment: is this Angular or React? What is "scrollToFixed"? i don't think it's jquery. you need to also post the javascript that contains "scrollToFixed"? ALSO: open your browser console and see what errors you are getting when you load the page and paste them in the question.

Comment: without posting this information, you'll never get an answer.

Comment: @Ringo there is no html for end-sticky, i am using a template and it was there already. I have added  **classname end** on footer div  and replaced end-sticky with end. Now the div(cube) stop scrolling between a third and half way down the page, rather than at the footer. Found something [similar to my issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615329/how-do-i-get-the-scrolltofix-plugin-limit-to-stop-at-my-websites-footer) , but the solution in it isnt working  for me

Comment: If you have a page to see, I could probably help. But there's not enough information here to recreate the issue, so I'm not sure what the problem is